# Auto start speech to text in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, speech-to-text

I am trying to start the speech input session without clicking on the microphone icon.
Like on window load or document load event - Instead of default click event.

> `<input type="text" id="autoStart" x-webkit-speech />`

I am using google chrome as it supports most of the HTML 5 features.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure if this would be possible it would be considered a privacy issue.

Comment: Yes, recording somebodys speech without permission should be a security issue, but nevertheless I want to achieve this task in order to start my project. Thanks for chipping in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate speech input recording in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751146/automate-speech-input-recording-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code on page load and you'll see a permissions dialogue asking you to grant microphone access. Click allow and speech to text recognition will begin. Check the speech recognition [API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) for events you can bind to.

```
var interim_result, final_result;
var recognition_engine = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition_engine.continuous = true;
recognition_engine.interimResults = true;
recognition_engine.lang = 'en-US';
recognition_engine.onresult = function(function(e) {

  var result, i;

  interim_result = '';
  if (typeof e.results === 'undefined') {

    recognition_engine.stop();
    console.log('SPEECH RECOGNITION : stopping due to empty result.', e);
    return;
  }
  for (i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
    result = event.results[i];
    if (result.isFinal) {
      final_result = result[0].transcript;
      console.log('SPEECH RECOGNITION : final transcript = ' + final_result, e);
      // trigger a command matching the final utterance here
    } else {
      interim_result += result[0].transcript;
    }
  }
  console.log('SPEECH RECOGNITION : interim result = ' + interim_result);
};
recognition_engine.start();
```